# VerifyError: Error #1014: Class JSON could not be found.

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi, I am a beginner in AS3 and came across this particular error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class JSON could not be found.

at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_callIn()
at Function/<anonymous>()
```

I was trying out the native JSON and everything seemed to be fine on the IDE (FlashDevelop). I am also using Flash Player 11, Flex SDK 4.6.0 and AIR 3.1 as describe on [Adobe AS3 Native JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#methodSummary)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have Flash player 11.2 playerglobal.swc located at:

> \frameworks\libs\player\11.X

where X denotes the Flash player 11 release version 1,2,3. Please also note that you need to specify the following in teh compilation constants:

> -swf-version=13 (FP11.1)
>
> -swf-version=15 (FP11.2)

Once you do that, you should be able to get the native JSON API working.

Comment: your talking about **FlashDevelop\Tools\flexlibs\frameworks\libs\player**
right?

Also can you elaborate more what you meant about the compilation constants? How exactly do I do that? Sorry I kinda new to AS3.

Comment: Yes, create a folder there name 11.2 and place the playerglobal.swc inside that folder. For the compilation constant, go to project properties "Compiler Options->Addition Compiler Constants". Define the constant there.